# How to pass authentication parameters from ignite thick client to server?

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

How to pass **authentication parameters from ignite thick client to server** ?. Is this an existing issue? If yes, when will be available ?. Can you please help us ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've written a plugin, you don't need to authenticate thick clients.

If you have written a plugin, then the details will be in your plugin. As an example, [here is how you configure authentication in GridGain](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/security/authentication) (the commercially supported version of Ignite).